# YouTube JS API: play by random time point on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to achieve playing a movie with YouTube JS API. There should be multiple time point in a single movie, so clicking on a button it would randomly pick any timepoint from the movie and start playing from there.

Here is my POC

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" 
type="text/html" width="720" height="405"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Comment: Could you display what you have so far. Display your attempt(s) too and explain what you think is the problem. Your question is lacking information and source code.

Comment: Thanks mplungjan...I need to make a POC for that but I was trying with this code:<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="720" height="405"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?rel=0&showinfo=0&theme=light"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> to add multiple time point..

Comment: So this isn't using the youtube API, you're just setting the iframe src to a youtube video embed...

Comment: Yes, I need to use the iFrmae embed. Maybe I can show a POC after couple of hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the embedded youtube `start` parameter to start the video at a given time. Create a function to generate a random number and then assign this random number to the start parameter.

See the jsfiddle attached as a demo. http://jsfiddle.net/y6dkwrov/6/

Every time you click the button it will change the start time to the video from a different point.

Let me know if this is the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @Bryce77, I have just seen that you are not using the Youtube API, and you are  embedding the video. I can show you how to do it for the iframe instead if you like. Let me know

Comment: Yes, I need to use tht iframe as I need to put the timepoints as attribute in HTML, so that it can be accessible from backend. If you can show that will be so helpful for me...Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! your are great...just what I was looking for...only one thing the timepoints should be as an array in attribute on html like data-time="5, 8, 2", it should pick from there randomly....Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bryce77 can you do the array part yourself, or do you need a hand? And also, you understand how this solution works?

Comment: yes understood. I will try the array part but if you cld give me a hand tht would be great. Thanks! I have updated the fiddle with data-time

Comment: yes Paul...I will try this and let you know...but your help was so helpful...thanks!

Comment: @Bryce77 no probs Bryce, I have updated the jsfiddle with the array answer you are looking for, but try crack it yourself before you look, you will learn more this way, and be able to do it all yourself next time.